# how to get unique upload url in BlobstoreUploadHandler (appengine)

Tags: google-app-engine, blobstore

```
from google.appengine.ext import blobstore
upload_url = blobstore.create_upload_url('/upload')
```

uplaod_url is an unique url, how do get it in the handler?

```
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import blobstore_handlers
class UploadHandler(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreUploadHandler):
  def post(self):
    upload_files = self.get_uploads('file')
    blob_info = upload_files[0]
    self.redirect('/serve/%s' % blob_info.key())
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't want it in the post handler. That's called after the file has already been uploaded, but the upload itself is handled by the App Engine internals.

Comment: I need to know who sent me the file. Having unique url in upload handler would do the thing. I could map unique url to userId in service calling create_upload_url, and in the uploadHandler get it back. I don't use Google Users API.

Comment: I don't see why you need the URL for that. The `post` method has access to the user ID just like every other handler, and the `blob_info` variable contains all the information you need to uniquely identify the blob (eg the blob key).